# Setting Visibility of an Element via Bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I got an UIElement with several Canvas which I want to show or hide depending on certain circumstances. I want this to be seen in the designer as well as when the program is running. I tried several Bindings and also the BooleanToVisibilityConverter. But I'm stuck and can't find my error. So here's the code:

**UIElement** (with only two Canvas; I got the responding properties in the partial Class)

```
<component:AbstractComponent x:Class="View.LineComponent"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:component="clr-namespace:View"
         x:Name="userControl" Width="70" Height="10"
>
    <component:AbstractComponent.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter" />
    </component:AbstractComponent.Resources>
    <Canvas Width="{Binding ElementName=userControl, Path=ActualWidth}">
        <Canvas Name="Line"
            Height="{Binding ElementName=userControl, Path=ActualHeight}"
            Width="{Binding ElementName=userControl, Path=ActualWidth}"
            Visibility="{Binding LineVisible, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=Hidden}"
            >
            <!-- Lot of stuff; Not interesting for the question-->
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas Name="Arrow"
            Height="{Binding ElementName=userControl, Path=ActualHeight, TargetNullValue=6.397, FallbackValue=6.397}"
            Width="{Binding ElementName=userControl, Path=ActualWidth, TargetNullValue=16.688, FallbackValue=16.688}"
            Visibility ="{Binding ArrowVisible, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=Hidden}"
            >
            <!-- Lot of stuff; Not interesting for the question-->
        </Canvas>
    </Canvas>
</component:AbstractComponent>
```

**Usage in ParentWindow**

```
<component:LineComponent Height="50" Canvas.Top="100" Width="50" Canvas.Left="50" LineVisible="True"/>

<component:LineComponent Height="50" Canvas.Top="200" Width="50" Canvas.Left="50" ArrowVisible="True"/>
```

I expect that in the first case the `Line`-Canvas is shown while in the other the `Arrow`-Canvas is shown. They both stay `Hidden` though. I also tried a different approach, declaring the `LineVisible` and `ArrowVisible` properties directly in the C#-Code but that didn't work either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `LineVisible` and `ArrowVisible` bindings do not have a source set, so will use the `DataContext` as source. You will make life easier for yourself if you set the `DataContext` of your root Canvas element to the user control allowing you to omit all the repeated `ElementName` bindings, as [described in this blog post I wrote](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2012/02/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight/).

Comment: Great! If only I had found your blog post a few hours earlier. This is exactly what I want to do. One question though: Do I have to type every Property as `string`? I tried to use `Visibility` which gives me an Exception saying that the used type does not fit the default value type.

Comment: @Nessuno glad it helped! ... "Do I have to type every Property as string?" no, use whatever type you require. You can expose a property of type Visibility and bind this to the UI.